# Can you pack $53$ bricks of dimensions $1\times 1\times 4$ into a $6\times 6\times 6$ box?

Tags: puzzle, packing-problem

> Can you pack 53 bricks of 1×1×4 size into 6×6×6 box?

Source: [puzzledquant.com](https://www.puzzledquant.com/problems/clgfh6ooh000qla08h7g6ok06)

My approach: I looked at the solution and visualized the box as $3d$ checkerboard. So in total we have $27$ such $2\times2\times2$ blocks. Now $14$ will be blue and $13$ red and each brick will be half blue and half red. So, total $52$ bricks will be used to fill it. Now, if it had been $6\times6\times7$ box, then too $52$ bricks only will be used. So, here we used the fact that $27$ is odd hence we divided into $14$ and $13$ and solved it. Is this correct? What if we had $28$ blocks then $14$ $14$ division and we would have fitted $14*4 = 56$ blocks here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original argument for the $6 \times 6 \times 6$ box is correct.  Color the box as a $2 \times 2 \times 2$ checkerboard.  There are $27\ 2 \times 2 \times 2$ cubes, $14$ black and $13$ white for a total of $112$ black cubes and $104$ white cubes.  Each $1 \times 1 \times 4$ block takes two black and two white cubes, so $52$ blocks is the maximum that can be placed.

This argument does not suffice for a $6 \times 6 \times 7$ box because you have an additional layer which can accommodate another $8 \ 1 \times 1 \times 4$ blocks.

Comment: Actually its not 27 2 X 2 X 2 cubes but 216 1 X 1 X 1 cubes. From this lens, there is no difference between the number of white and black cubes and they each count up to 108. Each block indeed takes up 2 black and 2 white cubes, so the total is 54. This is the mathematical limit, but the practical limit is 53.

Comment: @SeyiShoboyejo:  I can color it however I want.  I chose the $2 \times 2 \times 2$ blocks for my checkerboard because that makes the argument work.  Typically, as here, you want the blocks to take the same number of unit cubes of each color.

Comment: funny. I spent a few hours today cracking this puzzle during my interview prep! I did not realise there was no solution haha...

Comment: @SeyiShoboyejo:  there is an answer to the question asked, which is no.  This demonstrates that no is correct.

Comment: Oh I found some errors in my original solution. So I went back to work on it and I am now posting my solution as the answer. You should check it out. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Yes.

Divide the 6 X 6 X 6 cube into 3 layers of 6 X 6 X 2. Fill up the middle layer such that there are twice as many 1 X 1 holes in it than in the outer 2 layers. Hint: look for symmetry here.

Only 2 of the holes in the outer 2 layers coincide and 4/6 of their lengths are filled up with a single brick so that the space left in each of them is 2/6 of the length (or half a brick size).

The rest of the cube is completely filled up.

Here is a screenshot of the solution:

[image: Final arrangement of bricks in the cube]

Comment: You have only $52$ blocks.  There are $7$ flat in each of the top two layers, $6$ flat in the middle two, and $7$ in the bottom two for a total of $40$.  There are six upright ones that hit the top layer and six that hit the bottom.  That totals $52$

Comment: The holes in the upper right corner and lower left corner go all the way through.  The vertical blocks only fill 4 of the 6 spaces so that is four holes.  The columns next to them have a hole only two layers deep, which is four more holes.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to respond earlier. I went back to try to fix those errors you observed but I could not. I still think there could be a solution which might be easier to find empirically (in 3d) than using pen and paper.

Comment: My answer proves there is no way to place $53$ blocks.  Where do you find an error in it?